# Special Price suddenly not showing

Tags: magento2.2.4

The special price was showing fine and suddenly not showing.  I checked the Admin panel, the special price is still there. But not showing in the front end.  After I saved the product in all the store views then it displays on the front end again.

Does anyone have a similar issue?  Don't know why or when it will disappear.

Comment: Are these special prices migrated from M1 or imported? Did you do re-index?

Comment: I have same issue , Have you found the reason & solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the special price correctly then, you also need to check the following values;

**1. Special Price From**

**2. Special Price To**

If To Date is expired then it will not show in the frontend. If From date is a future date then it will also not work.

Check these values and reindex the system.